# JavaScript prototype property and prototype link

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I understand JavaScript prototype. But get confused with the difference between prototype property and hidden prototype link. Also difference between Object prototype link and Function prototype link ?

Could someone please provide a very basic example to demonstrate the same (mainly the prototype link/chaining...like how it looks up for the property in terms of both Object prototype link and Function prototype link)

Comment: I don't think there's any kind of hidden link. At least not these days. The prototype property is all there is to it. Also there is no difference between an object prototype and function prototype.

Comment: go here: nice read -
http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document Object Model(DOM) is a beautiful example of inheritance in JavaScript.

Imagine you have a `div`. It's an instance of `HTMLDivElement`.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div instanceof HTMLDivElement; // -> true

div instanceof HTMLElement; // -> true

div instanceof Element; // -> true

div instanceof Object; // -> true
```

`div` is an *Object* and includes all methods and properties that is in `HTMLDivElement.prototype`. It's under `__proto___` property but it doesn't mean you should do `div.__proto__.insertBefore` to access `insertBefore`. It's like an include in other languages.

In other words `div.__proto__` is pointing to `HTMLDivElement.prototype`.

`prototype` is an Object. Because of that, it can have it's own `__proto__` pointer. In this Case `HTMLDivElement`'s `prototype` is an Object and have a `__proto__` that is pointing to `HTMLElement.prototype`, so it includes all methods and properties. It goes down this path until `Object.prototype` that doesn't have a `__proto__` pointer and lookup stups.

I tried to avoid using `new` keyword for explaining this. I hope it helps...